# Bad Memory Allocation when trying to use a SLL of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I have created a SLL that is filled with array objects of size [2].  The goal is to use a SLL to save a list of usernames and passwords.  I have a list of names in a file.  I am able to read the list and write the last names to a new file.  However, when I make the objects in the SLL all arrays and try to save a corresponding password with a username, I get a bad allocation error when trying to access the arrays.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
LinkedList* listOfNames = new LinkedList[2]();


void readFile(std::string newFile){
    ifstream inFile(newFile);
    std::string firstWord;
    
    while(inFile >> firstWord)
    {
        listOfNames[0].InsertAtHead(firstWord);
        listOfNames[1].InsertAtHead("password");
        inFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    inFile.close();
}

void writeFile(std::string outFilename)
{
    Node *temp = new Node[2];
    temp = listOfNames->getHead();
    ofstream outFile(outFilename);
    
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        outFile << temp[0].GetValue() << "        "   << temp[1].GetValue() << std::endl;
        temp = temp->GetNext();
    }
    outFile.close();
}
```

If I comment out the line where I try to access the 2 items in an array, then it runs fine.

```
outFile << temp[0].GetValue() << "        "   << temp[1].GetValue() << std::endl
```

I know that I have a memory allocation issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Below are my LinkedList.cpp and Node.cpp.  They are last because they may be uneccesary.

```
Node::Node()
{
    this->value = "";
    this->next = nullptr;
}

Node::Node(std::string value)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->next = nullptr;
}


std::string Node::GetValue()
{
    return this->value;
}

void Node::SetNext(Node* next)
{
    this->next = next;
}


Node* Node::GetNext()
{
    return this->next;
}
```

```
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->tail = nullptr;
    this->size = 0;
}


void LinkedList::InsertAtHead(std::string value)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node(value);
    newNode->SetNext(this->head);
    this->head = newNode;
    if(this->tail == nullptr)
    {
        this->tail = newNode;
    }
    this->size++;
}

void LinkedList::Print()
{
    Node* currentNode = this->head;
    while(currentNode != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << currentNode->GetValue() << std::endl;
        currentNode = currentNode->GetNext();
    }

}

Node* LinkedList::getHead()
{
    return this-> head;
}
```

Node.hpp

```
class Node
{
    private:
        std::string value;
        Node* next;
    public:
        Node();
        Node(std::string value);
        std::string GetValue();
        void SetNext(Node* next);
        Node* GetNext();

};
```

linked_list.hpp

```
class LinkedList
{
    private:
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
        int size;
    public:
        LinkedList();
        void InsertAtHead(std::string value);
        void Print();
        Node* getHead();

};

#endif
```

Comment: Seems like a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Please provide the Node declaration here too! At first sight: this is a quite questionable design: Node *temp = new Node[2]; And then further on implicitly assuming the types fit within the iteration... Mixing pure single object semantics with array semantics. Maybe it's also the cause of your crash.

Comment: @Secundi I added my declarations.  Can you help me with the direction of a better solution please?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue.  I was trying to access objects that were never created.  I am not that good with a debugger, but I was able to use small samples to test my output.  I ended up changing my node class to accept 2 values.  This way I don't have to create an array.  I can use an SLL and have each node hold 2 values.  This keeps me from trying to mix pointers with nonpointers.  Thank you for the insight!

Comment: You're welcome! :) General hint here: If you have to refer to raw pointers, try to make them internal as far as possible, don't expose them too much (if internal information has to be exposed, refer to shared_ptr/unique_ptr or similar wrappers!).